# Is there a way to find out which software gets triggered when I press a particular key combination in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I am getting some weird activity (endless RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR when I press windows-shift-R button) under Windows 10.

I used to use software that used this shortcut, but then I changed that shortcut to something else.

So now I'm getting this nonsense whenever I use the old key combination by mistake.

I'm wondering if there is a way to figure out what is being triggered when I press that key-combo and, more importantly, a way to stop this from happening.